# Donut bubble chart in D3.js version 3

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I need to plot bubble chart, where each bubble is a donut chart like in below image in d3 version 3. I am able to achieve something, but don't understand how to distribute the circles horizontally, as my widget will be rectangular.

Also, how to make the donut bubble like in the image below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]
Code:

```js
let colorCircles = {
  'a': '#59bcf9',
  'b': '#faabab',
  'd': '#ffde85'
};
let tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip-inner")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("min-width", "12rem")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .style("color", "#627386")
  .style("padding", "15px")
  .style("stroke", '#b8bfca')
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)
  .style("background-color", "#fff")
  .style("border-radius", "6px")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .text("");

let bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([width, diameter])
  .padding(15)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d[columnForRadius];
  });

let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

let nodes = bubble.nodes({
  children: dataset
}).filter(function(d) {
  return !d.children;
});

let circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y - 20;
  })

  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorCircles[d[columnForColors]]
  })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    tooltip.html('<p>' + d[columnForColors] + ": " + d[columnForText] + "</p><div class='font-bold displayInlineBlock'> $" + d[columnForRadius] + '</div>');
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.offsetY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.offsetX + 10) + "px");
  })
  // .on("mouseout", function() {
  //     return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  // })
  .attr("class", "node");

circles.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .each('end', function() {
    display_text();
  });

function display_text() {
  let text = svg
    .selectAll(".text")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d[columnForText];
    });

  text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "graphText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".2em")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.r / 5;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      console.log(d)
      return d[columnForText].substring(0, d.r / 3);
    });

  text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "graphText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return '$' + d[columnForRadius];
    })
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.r / 5;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");
}

function hide_text() {
  let text = svg.selectAll(".text").remove();
}

d3.select(self.frameElement)
  .style("height", diameter + "px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataset = [
    { "Name": "Olives",          "Count": 4319, "Category": "d" },
    { "Name": "Tea",             "Count": 4159, "Category": "d" },
    { "Name": "Boiled Potatoes", "Count": 2074, "Category": "a" },
    { "Name": "Milk",            "Count": 1894, "Category": "a" },
    { "Name": "Chicken Salad",   "Count": 1809, "Category": "a" },
    { "Name": "Lettuce Salad",   "Count": 1566, "Category": "a" },
    { "Name": "Lobster Salad",   "Count": 1511, "Category": "a" },
    { "Name": "Chocolate",       "Count": 1489, "Category": "b" }
  ];

  var width = 300, diameter = 300;
  var columnForText = 'Name',
  columnForColors = 'Category', 
  columnForRadius = "Count";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/71s86zL7/

I created a compound bubble pie chart and specified the inner radius in the pie chart.

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius)
  .outerRadius(radius);

.attr("d", function(d) {
    arc.innerRadius(d.r+5);
    arc.outerRadius(d.r);
    return arc(d);
})
```

please let me know if there's any alternative solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you specify what the problem is?

Comment: @uditya This is actually how I wanted it to look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a sorta hacky solution for this. What I did was:

1. to use the `d3.layout.pie` to get the `startAngles` and `endAngles` for `arcs` and create the `arcs` on top of the `circles`.
2. Give the `circles` a stroke line creating an effect of a donut chart.
3. And then I just had to adjust the `startAngles` and the `endAngles` so that all the `arcs` start from the same position.

Here's the fiddle:

```js
let colorCircles = {
  'a': '#59bcf9',
  'b': '#faabab',
  'd': '#ffde85'
};
let tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip-inner")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("min-width", "12rem")
  .style("visibility", "hidden")
  .style("color", "#627386")
  .style("padding", "15px")
  .style("stroke", '#b8bfca')
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke-width", 1)
  .style("background-color", "#fff")
  .style("border-radius", "6px")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .text("");

let bubble = d3.layout.pack()
  .sort(null)
  .size([width, diameter])
  .padding(15)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d[columnForRadius];
  });

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.Count;
  });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()

let svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

let nodes = bubble.nodes({
  children: dataset
}).filter(function(d) {
  return !d.children;
});

let g = svg.append('g')

let circles = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y - 20;
  })

  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorCircles[d[columnForColors]]
  })
  .attr("class", "node")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    tooltip.html('<p>' + d[columnForColors] + ": " + d[columnForText] + "</p><div class='font-bold displayInlineBlock'> $" + d[columnForRadius] + '</div>');
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.offsetY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.offsetX + 10) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  });

arcs = g.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

arcs.append("path")
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate(' + d['data']['x'] + ',' + (d['data']['y'] - 20) + ')';
  })
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return arc({
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: d.startAngle - d.endAngle,
      innerRadius: d['data']['r'] - 2,
      outerRadius: d['data']['r'] + 2,
    })
  }).on("mouseover", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    tooltip.html('<p>' + d['data'][columnForColors] + ": " + d['data'][columnForText] + "</p><div class='font-bold displayInlineBlock'> $" + d['data'][columnForRadius] + '</div>');
  })
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.offsetY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.offsetX + 10) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
  });

circles.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .each('end', function() {
    display_text();
  });

function display_text() {
  let text = svg
    .selectAll(".text")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d[columnForText];
    });

  text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "graphText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".2em")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.r / 3;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d[columnForText].substring(0, d.r / 3);
    });

  text.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "graphText")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return d.y - 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", "1.3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return '$' + d[columnForRadius];
    })
    .attr("font-size", function(d) {
      return d.r / 5;
    })
    .attr("fill", "white");
}

function hide_text() {
  let text = svg.selectAll(".text").remove();
}

d3.select(self.frameElement)
  .style("height", diameter + "px");
```

```css
path {
  fill: orange;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: crimson;
}

path:hover {
  fill: yellow;
}

circle {
  fill: white;
  stroke: slategray;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.13/d3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataset = [{
      "Name": "Olives",
      "Count": 4319,
      "Category": "d"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Tea",
      "Count": 4159,
      "Category": "d"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Boiled Potatoes",
      "Count": 2074,
      "Category": "a"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Milk",
      "Count": 1894,
      "Category": "a"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chicken Salad",
      "Count": 1809,
      "Category": "a"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Lettuce Salad",
      "Count": 1566,
      "Category": "a"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Lobster Salad",
      "Count": 1511,
      "Category": "a"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Chocolate",
      "Count": 1489,
      "Category": "b"
    }
  ];

  var width = 300,
    diameter = 300;
  var columnForText = 'Name',
    columnForColors = 'Category',
    columnForRadius = "Count";
</script>
```